# Use modules from a repo in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use some modules from `pyModeS` in columns of a pandas data frame.

The data frame in question is this one:

```
                                reply  timeAtServer  aircraftAddress
0        8daa6c326099d400d47d1e63b4c4  1.557497e+09         11168818
1                      5daa6c32b53e75  1.557497e+09         11168818
2                      5daa6c32b53e75  1.557497e+09         11168818
3        8daa6c32234d7076d79e20295623  1.557497e+09         11168818
4        a41982db7067fdae209e5d93b760  1.557497e+09         11168818
                              ...           ...              ...
1074083                02c1873a45a781  1.558654e+09         11339810
1074084                02c6073b626e6b  1.558654e+09         11339810
1074085                5dad7f539b6bea  1.558654e+09         11370323
1074086  8dad082299094b82e100172dd23f  1.558654e+09         11339810
1074087                02c1873bba5388  1.558654e+09         11339810

[1074088 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to create new columns (DF, TC and RA) based on the column 'reply', what I have done so far is this:

```
df['DF'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.df(x))
df['TC'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.adsb.typecode(x))
df['RA'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.bds.bds30.is30(x) if len(x) > 14 else '...')
```

This works fine, but **I believe there must be a more elegant, quicker way to do this**.

NOTE: `pms.df(x)` gives integers, `pms.adsb.typecode(x)` gives integers and 'NaN', `pms.bds.bds30.is30(x)` gives booleans (True or False).

Also, based on the first column again, I would like to apply a module (`pms.adsb.icao(x)`) but only to the rows of `reply` that have `RA` on 'True'. That is like a double condition or something similar and I cannot get my head around it.

For the moment the only thing I have been able to do is getting the indices of RA when is True, and then making a loop to write the new column, but **this takes forever**:

```
IDX = df.index[df['RA'] == True].tolist()

for x in IDX:
    df['icao24'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.adsb.icao(x))
```

This is the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyModeS as pms
    
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop\opensky_tcas_incidents_raw_dedup.csv')
    
df['DF'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.df(x))
df['TC'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.adsb.typecode(x))
df['RA'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x:  pms.bds.bds30.is30(x) if len(x) > 14 else '...')
    
IDX = df.index[df['RA'] == True].tolist()

for x in IDX:
    df['icao24'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.adsb.icao(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function, unfortunately performance depends of `pms` module processing:

```
def f(x):
    DF = pms.df(x)
    TC = pms.adsb.typecode(x)
    RA = pms.bds.bds30.is30(x) if len(x) > 14 else '...'
    icao24 = pms.adsb.icao(x) if RA == 'True' else None
    return pd.Series([DF, TC, RA, icao24])
    
df[['DF','TC','RA','icao24']] = df['reply'].apply(f)
```

Your code should be optimalzied only in second part, in first only possible remove some lambdas:

```
df['DF'] = df['reply'].apply(pms.df)
df['TC'] = df['reply'].apply(pms.adsb.typecode)
df['RA'] = df['reply'].apply(lambda x:  pms.bds.bds30.is30(x) if len(x) > 14 else '...')

mask = df['RA'] == 'True'
df.loc[mask, 'icao24'] = df.loc[mask, 'reply'].apply(lambda x: pms.adsb.icao(x))
```

Comment: As you said, this custom function is elegant but it is much slower than my MWE. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @PeterLaAnguila - Yes, Added your code optimalized for `icao24`

Comment: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['...', '...', '...', '...', '...',\n       ...\n       '...', '...', '...', '...', '...'],\n      dtype='object', length=692832). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"

Comment: @PeterLaAnguila - hmm, so `'True'` is string? Then use `mask = df['RA'] == 'True'`